# Magento Extension for vendor verification

Tags: module, admin, extensions, adminform

I'm developing an extension for vendor verification. What i want to develop is to get input from vendor i-e token and validate that input through curl response if the response matches the token then save the token in database.My extension structure.
[image]

When i clicked save config button the api token field is getting saved in core_config_data table.
I want to know what steps should i take now to develop this extension. where should i write the validation code in model or controller.

Comment: validation is always written in controller

Comment: which kind of validation do you want for API token ?

Comment: user will enter token in api token field and if that token matches the response from curl than the token should store in database